# 4+1 div ordering CSS

Tags: html, css

My form is generating 4 small and 1 large div containers. Is it possible to arrange them by CSS only (as on picture), and without using additional left/right group divs?
[image]

Div 1-4 width around 25%, 
Div 5 width around 50%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
    .div1, .div2, .div3, .div4 {width: 25%; float:left;}
    .div3 {clear:left;}
    .div5 {display:inline-block; width: 50%;}
```

and than I make divs:

```
    <div>
    <div class="div1">First DIV</div>
    <div class="div2">Second DIV</div>
    <div class="div3">Third DIV</div>
    <div class="div4">Fourth DIV</div>
    <div class="div5">Fifth DIV</div>
    </div>
```

Works on a test page. On a downside, I should mention that this is not responsive layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nth-child:

```
div:nth-child(5n){
  /* style your every fifth element */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea but I'll need more than that. Maybe a code example if I am not asking for too much?

Comment: I've posted below a a variation of my current code. It's simple jet not responsive. 
Responsive is not required, but it would be lovely to have it.